# Same array keys into one and seperate values into array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays like this

1st

```
Array
(
    [0] => Test
    [1] => Test2
    [2] => Test2
    [3] => Test
)
```

2nd

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => A
    [2] => B
    [3] => B
)
```

I'm trying to stick them together with seperated commas or array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Test] => A, B
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Test2] => A, B
        )
)
```

Comment: Where are the `1`, `2` supposed to be coming from?

Comment: From the second array check out the 2nd array

Comment: Simple `foreach` loop should do shouldn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm simply not understanding what the logic is supposed to be, could you maybe explain to me what you are trying to accomplish in the end?

Comment: Stick the 2 arrays together with same keys into one key value

Comment: Thanks, your edit makes things much easier to understand :)

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish this in the end? `Array
(
    [Test] => Array
        (
            0 => A,
            1 => B
        )

    [Test2] => Array
        (
            0 => A,
            1 => B
        )
)`

Comment: Yeap I sticked them together but can't seperate them with commas into one array key

Comment: Exactly this `Array ( [Test] => Array ( 0 => A, 1 => B ) [Test2] => Array ( 0 => A, 1 => B ) )`

Comment: Alright, give me a second, this should just be a simple foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the solution you are looking for.

```
$first = array(
    '0' => 'Test',
    '1' => 'Test2',
    '2' => 'Test2',
    '3' => 'Test'
);

$second = array(
    '0' => 'A',
    '1' => 'A',
    '2' => 'B',
    '3' => 'B'
);

$unique_second = array_unique( $second );
$result = array();

foreach ( array_unique( $first ) as $unique_value_from_first ) {
    $result[ $unique_value_from_first ] = $unique_second;
}

print_r( $result );
```

This will result in this:

```
Array
(
    [Test] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [2] => B
        )
    [Test2] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [2] => B
        )
)
```

I tested with this: http://www.tehplayground.com/#6xJEuK10J

I don't understand the need to do this, considering `$unique_second` array won't be changing, but have fun.

Also, for future reference, you answer has been down-voted because you are asking for code logic help which is frowned upon. Please catch up on your reading: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: Thank you. I want this to return json data

Comment: @idkAnything, there is a function called json_encode(). You can find this in the PHP Manual.